# Composition of $H^2$ functions

Tags: sobolev-spaces, function-and-relation-composition

Suppose $\Omega$ is a sufficiently smooth bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $f \in H^2(\Omega) = W^{2,2}(\Omega)$ and $g \in H^2(\Omega) \cap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

Can we say that $g \circ f \in H^2(\Omega)$?

I tried looking at other questions here but they only have composition with smooth or Lipschitz functions.

Comment: You cannot compose $f$ and $g$. You need $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ otherwise the composition makes no sense

Comment: You are right! Is it enough to take g in $C^2$ then? Or maybe $g \in H^2(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^{\infty} (\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g(0)=0$, it is enough to have $g\in H^2_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R})$. This is a theorem due to Bourdau.
See Theorem 12.72 in [Sobolev book](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-181).
If $g(0)\ne 0$
and $g\in H^2_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R})$,
define $h(t)=g(t)-g(0)$. Then $h\circ f \in H^2(\Omega)$. In turn, so does $g\circ f=h\circ f+g(0)$ since constants are in $H^2$ in bounded domains.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful! I checked the reference but I could not find Theorem 12.72, is that a typo?

Comment: There are two editions

Comment: Sure! I will check it. 
I have another question, if this holds in $\mathbb{R}$ can we restrict it to subdomains of $\mathbb{R}$? If we take $g : [0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ and of course we have here $f: \Omega \to [0, \infty)$.

Comment: If the subdomains are nice enough, yes, because you can always extend $g$ to the entire space keeping it in the same Sobolev space.

Comment: Alright, much appreciated.